# Strategies for mixing in the gwt compatible and non compatible source

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

Yes i know one alternative to solving this problem is simply to create two source directories from the original. The class path for the GWT compiler would thus be setup to simply only see the compatible source while both would be used for the server portion of your app.

Firstly i find this kind of ugly, because it means i now have two source directories with potential doubles of classes.

- refactoring and other structural abilities of the IDE can potentially be problematic as it will get confused.
- Sometimes its not possible to put some stuff in separate packages: think client and server packages simply because one would then have to make something public which should really be package private to limit scope accessibility.
- is there a library that enables classes or methods to marked as ignored by the GWT compiler ?

Is there a better way ?

Comment: There is now a solution to this (in GWT 2.6), an annotation: [GwtIncompatible](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/shared/GwtIncompatible.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude classes (files actually) from GWT's source path using Ant-like includes/excludes: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuidePathFiltering
You cannot exclude methods or inner classes though, it really is file-based. See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3769

Answer (score 2):

Make a `shared` directory that has the code that both the GWT side and server side can read.  Any classes that would be duplicated instead go into this folder, to be accessed (without duplication!) from both client- and server-sides of your app.

Comment: As i mentioned in the q, tahts exactly what i DONT want to do because of the fragmentation it causes. It also does not solve the problem - of how to skip a method (without extracting it) that is not gwt cmpatible.

Comment: To be clear, I'm suggesting creating THREE source directories, which will help you avoid any code duplication at all.  In the end, your GWT app and your server app are two different programs, and it's unreasonable to expect them to share a single code base.  You could make a preprocessor that causes GWT to ignore certain classes, probably, but I don't think having certain methods that suddenly just fail to work is much better than having to design your classes in separate packages with a few extra public methods.